# How to reduce the tab navigator header to the status bar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabnavigator

I'm using a bottom tab navigator and its Header. But my header is longer than I want to. It is on the status bar and I want to reduce it. How can I reduce the Header in its top margin? I already tried to use `marginTop` in `headerStyle` but it says that it doesn't work in `headerStyle`.

```
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={TabNavigator}
              options={{
                headerShown: true,
                headerStyle: {
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(8, 0, 122, 0.91)',
                  marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerLeft: null,
                headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  alignSelf: 'center',
                }}}/>
```

And nothing happens. I can't embed a picture and I don't know why :/ What can I do???

Answer (score 0):

In your case the header is not overlapping with the status bar. The reason it looks like it is overlapping is because changing the background color on `headerStyle` will change the color of the status bar also.

So if you want to make the status bar distinct from the header simply give the status bar a background color also:

`StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("blue");`

You can put this in your main app component inside a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array or if you're using a class inside `componentDidMount`.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#setbackgroundcolor